# Ho To Skip/Avoid Setup Guide After Factory Reset?

Tags: android

I want to create a app where the user can factory reset its device. I already know that its done with the `DevicePolicyManager`. After the wipe, Google docs say, a reboot happens.

> Calling from the primary user will cause the device to reboot, erasing all device data - including all the secondary users and their data - while booting up.

Now my question is: After reboot is it possible to avoid the set up guide of the Android System or is it even possible to still execute some code to do it for the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless this is a personal device where you can override the default factory image.  You just reset the device-  even if you could set a flag somewhere to skip it, resetting the device would erase the flag.

Now if this is a personal device and you overwrite the recovery image you can use a recovery image that's already past that point.  But not on a generic app.